# YetAnotherForum problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, yetanotherforum

is there anyone using yetanotherforum. I'm getting a different problems while installing the forum.

1. When I try to run the myapplication/yetanotherforum/install/default.aspx --> Two rows inserted in the table yaf_prov_application (i.forums, ii.yetanotherforum)
2. After that When I finish the details of admin it is showing error like

Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UserID', table 'duckyforum.dbo.yaf_prov_RoleMembership'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Can somebody give me the solution. I'm working on the same issue from last 3 days.

Thanks in advance,
Nagu

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been reported to YAF dev team and has been fixed in svn no. 3475. Download the latest source from sourceforge and there should be no problem.